# JQuery: detect which span id has class="active" and if button is pressed go to another span id

Tags: jquery, html, detect

I've got already one script that is toggling between every of span ids i've listed below adding class active and removing it so only 1 span id element is visible.

```
<div id="b_pager">
<span id="p1" class="active"></span>
<span id="p2"></span>
<span id="p3"></span>
<span id="p4"></span>
<span id="p5"></span>
</div>
```

Now what i want to do, is make two buttons (sort of arrows) that will allow to navigate throught span ids.

Example: 
If span id p3 is visible and arrow right -> is pressed automatically go to span id p4. If pressed arrow left <- go back to p3, and so on.

Any one can help? Thanks in advance.

Matt

Comment: What have you tried? Please come up with some initial code, when you have a issue come up with the specific issue you are having.

Comment: What does this "toggling" script do? Provide your own attempt or at least an idea on how to approach your problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

working demo
http://jsfiddle.net/HhUBR/

**CODE**

```
$('#next').click(function() {
    if ($('span:last').hasClass('active')) {
        $('#next').attr('disabled', true)
    }
    else {
        $('.active').removeClass().next().addClass('active');
    }
})

$('#prev').click(function() {
    if ($('span').eq(0).hasClass('active')) {
        $('#prev').attr('disabled', true)
    }
    else {
        $('.active').removeClass().prev().addClass('active')
    }
})​
```

Answer (score 1):

Use [`.eq()`](http://api.jquery.com/eq/) in conjunction with modular arithmetic to cycle the values:

```
$("#next,#prev").click(function () {
  var $pager = $("#b_pager"),
      $spans = $pager.find("span"),
      activeIdx = $spans.filter(".active").removeClass("active").index();
  if (this.id == "next") {
    $spans.eq((activeIdx + 1) % $spans.length).addClass("active");
  } else {
    $spans.eq(activeIdx - 1).addClass("active");
  }
});
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/g8Rsd/)**.

Comment: great solution!!!, we can omit ` if (activeIdx == 0) {activeIdx =$spans.length;}` as eq also works with negative index: **[demo](http://jsfiddle.net/teyK2/1/)**

Answer (score 1):

My attempt,

JS

```
 $(document).ready(function() {
        var counter = 0;
        $('#right_btn').click(function () {
           var spans  = $('#b_pager').find('span');
           var index = ++counter % spans.length;   // TO CYCLE 
           spans.eq(index - 1 ).removeClass('active').end()
             .eq(index).addClass('active');
        });
    });​
```

HTML

```
<div id="b_pager">
<span id="p1" class="active">first</span>
<span id="p2">second</span>
<span id="p3">third</span>
<span id="p4">forth</span>
<span id="p5">fifth</span>
</div>
<button id='right_btn'>Right</button>
​
```

CSS:

```
 #b_pager span {
     display:none;
    }

    #b_pager span.active {
     display:block;
    }
```

​
http://jsfiddle.net/sqBQ9/

Answer (score 0):

you can use `jQuery.next(".active")` to select next object, to get previous use `jQuery.prev(".active")`

Here is the working demo

http://jsfiddle.net/LGBY8/

```
$("#next").click(function() {
    var or = $(".active");
    if($(".active").next().length!=0)
     $(".active").next().addClass("active");
    else
        $($(".active").parent().children().get(0)).addClass("active");
    $(or).removeClass("active");
})
$("#previous").click(function() {
    var or = $(".active");
    if($(".active").prev().length!=0)
     $(".active").prev().addClass("active");
    else
        $($(".active").parent().children().get(-1)).addClass("active");
    $(or).removeClass("active");
})
```

​